# using flask-admin and sqlalchemy; now i am trying to make a form to add/delete/edit my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I create a custom view that organizes all of my products and services in an accordion-like fashion so that the data is user friendly.  Below is my custom view:

```
class productView(BaseView):
    form_columns = ['name','price']
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        myServ = Product.query.all()
        myProd =  Productcategories.query.all()
        return self.render('admin/products.html', myProd = myProd, myServ = myServ)


admin.add_view(productView(name='Products and Services', endpoint='products'))
```

I then proceeded to make my HTML view and that has worked like gangbusters.  Where I'm at now is that I've created some buttons that user my jquery to load a modal.  That works great as well.  However, I'm somewhat stuck in the next step.

Once I hit the "submit" button, how do I tell it to add/delete/edit the particular item?

```js
//button scripts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-category-item").click(function() {
    $('.bg-modal').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('.bg-modal').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".subtract-category-item").click(function() {
    $('.bg-modal').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('.bg-modal').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit-category-item").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).attr("data-parent");
    $('#papa').val(parent);
    console.log("the parent caregory is:" + parent);
    $('.bg-modal').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('.bg-modal').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<li> {{prod.category_name}} <a class="edit-category-item" data-parent="{{prod.parent_category_id}}" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> <a class="subtract-category-item" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>  <a class="add-category-item" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>


<a class="edit-service-item" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> <a class="subtract-service-item" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a> <a class="add-service-item" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div style="display: none;" class="bg-modal">
  <div class="modal-contents">

    <div class="close">+</div>

    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name of category">
      <input type="text" id="papa">
      <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using flask-admin generic delete and edit views you could expose a route that will do the delete/edit for you and add this route as your form `action`

for example

```
class productView(BaseView):
    form_columns = ['name','price']
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        myServ = Product.query.all()
        myProd =  Productcategories.query.all()
        return self.render('admin/products.html', myProd = myProd, myServ = myServ)

    @expose('/custom_delete')
    def custom_delete(self):
        # write custom code to delete from the database
        return self.render('admin/products.html', myProd = myProd, myServ = myServ)
```

Then in your HTML

```
<div style="display: none;" class="bg-modal">
  <div class="modal-contents">

    <div class="close">+</div>

    <form action="{{url_for('.custom_delete')}}">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name of category">
      <input type="text" id="papa">
      <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Your form will get submitted to the endpoint where you can take care of the delete action in your backend

Comment: After banging my head at other parts, i just want to make sure you know that this worked!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Awesome! happy I was able to help